# Save/Export "any" mathematica window in .nb

Tags: export, notebooks, files-and-directories, documentation, save

Can I call this (a tutorial page) a mathematica notebook?
At least it is a kind of mathematica window, which looks like a common .nb file.

[image]

Is it possible to **Save/Export** this mathematica window **in .nb** on my local disk **just as it looks**, I mean, **including the areas painted with a yellow highlighter pen** ?
(Functionally  it doesn't matter whether the search bar actually works or not)

The question can be generalized to the following :
**Can we save/export any mathematica window in .nb ?**

The question is **not** about the location of tutorial file.
Not relevant to the question, but it is located at
C:\Users\UERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Wolfram Research\Documentation.en-us\13.1\Documentation\English\System\ReferencePages\Symbols\ModularInverse.nb

Comment: You could screen capture the window.

Comment: `CurrentScreenImage[]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Export["file.nb", NotebookObject[...]]` to programmatically export any notebook that is currently open in the front end. As a concrete example:

```
CreatePalette@Button["Export!", Export["output.nb", InputNotebook[]]]
```

Focusing on the documentation browser and pressing the "Export!" button in the palette created above will create a file called `output.nb`, which looks like this when opened:

[image]

Comment: The solution really works!